# Fourier series of $x(\pi-x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Find the Fourier series of

$$f(x)=x(\pi-x) ,\text{ } -\pi \le x \le \pi$$

Sketch the graph of the series for $x \in [-3\pi, 3\pi]$.

By evaluating $f(x)$ at particular points, deduce the sum of the following series

(i) $$\frac{1}{1^2}-\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}+...$$

(ii) $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

---

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}(x-\pi-x^2)\cos{nx}\text{ }dx$$

$$=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x\cos{nx}\text{ }dx-\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x^2\cos{nx}\text{ }dx$$

$$=-\frac{4}{n}(-1)^n$$

$$a_0= \frac{2}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}(x\pi-x^2)\text{ }dx=-\frac{4\pi^2}{3}$$

$$b_n=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x\cos{nx}\text{ }dx-\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x^2\cos{nx}\text{ }dx=-\frac{4}{n^2}(-1)^n$$

$$f(x)=-\frac{4\pi^2}{3}-4\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cos{nx}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\sin{nx}$$

The graph is ok for me.

Now, to prove the series

Putting $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (pt. of cty)

$$\frac{\pi}{2}=-\frac{4\pi^2}{3}-4\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}.(-1)^n$$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}=-\frac{\pi}{24}(3+8\pi)$$

But I am unsure of this. And I need some hints for the other series.

Comment: It is clear that the result is incorrect, since the sum is positive.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, Could you please more elaborate, I don'understand what you mean?

Comment: Your last equation, Sirus, the left side is a sum of positive numbers, hence, positive, while the right side is clearly a negative number, so something has gone very wrong.

Comment: For $a_n $, your function $f(x)$ looks wrong.  Why don't you go back and write each $a_0, a_n, b_n $ from the definition. Don't expand it like you have, your three coefficients are begun in different stages.  Start each at the beginning, walk them through, take your time.

Comment: I shall try it again friends, thank you for pointing out where I went wrong.

Comment: Also, $a_0$ should be divided by $2 \pi $, I believe.  Not $\pi $